# How to add jquery bounce animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

In the following code I am trying to enable the `li` elements of the page to bounce. However when I run the code nothing happens. What I am doing which causes the elements not to bounce? I would appreciate any help

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul.main_menu li").on("load", function (){
        $(this).show().animate({ marginTop: "80px" }, 1500 )
               .animate({ marginTop: "40px" }, 800 );
    });
});
```

```css
/*less file*/
.main_menu {
    display: inline;
    li {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 32px;
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        &:first-child {
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
    }
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: @color_1;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        outline: none;
    }
    li.active {
        &:focus {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #C80813;
        }
        &:active {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #C80813;
        }
        border-bottom: 2px solid #C80813;
        &:hover {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #C80813;
        }
        &:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 27px;
            right: 43%;
            border: 5px solid transparent;
            border-top-color: #C80813;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main_menu">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" data-id="#about">About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#choose">Why choose us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If my answer works for you would you consider accepting it. If it doesn't please leave a comment and I will edit it so that it does work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just doing

```
$('ul.main_menu li').show().animate({ marginTop: "80px" }, 1500 ).animate({ marginTop: "40px" }, 800 );
```

This will work as you already have a `$(document).ready()` function so it will happen when the `li` components are `ready` to be interacted with by the browser

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0d3wexp/) example

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0d3wexp/1/) with your code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.main_menu li').show().animate({ marginTop: "80px" }, 1500 ).animate({ marginTop: "40px" }, 800 );
});
```

```css
**less file**
.main_menu {
    display: inline;
    li {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 32px;
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        &:first-child {
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
    }
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: @color_1;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        outline: none;
    }
    li.active {
        &:focus {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #C80813;
        }
        &:active {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #C80813;
        }
        border-bottom: 2px solid #C80813;
        &:hover {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #C80813;
        }
        &:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 27px;
            right: 43%;
            border: 5px solid transparent;
            border-top-color: #C80813;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script type = "text/javascript" 
 src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="main_menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" data-id="#about">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#choose">Why choose us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Prasath1992 No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

On load events can not be attached to `ul` or `li` elements, it can be attached with only document or external resources. If you want bounce animation on page load than the below snippet can can help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".main_menu li").effect( "bounce", { distance: 120 }, "slow" );
});
```

```css
**less file**
.main_menu {
    display: inline;
    li {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 32px;
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        &:first-child {
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
    }
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: @color_1;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        outline: none;
    }
    li.active {
        &:focus {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #C80813;
        }
        &:active {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #C80813;
        }
        border-bottom: 2px solid #C80813;
        &:hover {
            border-bottom: 2px solid #C80813;
        }
        &:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 27px;
            right: 43%;
            border: 5px solid transparent;
            border-top-color: #C80813;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript" 
 src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul class="main_menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" data-id="#about">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#choose">Why choose us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, that it did not work for you. Could you let me know what went wrong ?

Comment: Sorry yours too works bro... Partially... that shows the exact result.